# How to set default value for the button in spoiler?

Tags: jquery, html, button

I have this spoiler code.

HTML:

```
<input type='button' class="splLink" value='Show'>
<div class="splCont">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.<br />
    <input type='button' class="splLink" value='Show'>
    <div class="splCont">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. <br />
        <input type='button' class="splLink" value='Show'>
        <div class="splCont">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".splLink").click(function() {
        $(this).next().slideToggle("fast");
        $(this).val($(this).val() == 'Show' ? 'Hide' : 'Show'); 
        return false; 
    });
});
```

CSS:

```
.splCont {
    display: none; 
    padding-top: 10pt;
}
.splLink {
    font-family: arial, verdana, ms sans serif;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Example: [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/BrNQL/)

Can anyone tell me how to add the default value for the button in code,
that I could use the spoiler in html without value attribute? Something like that:

```
<input type='button' class="splLink">
<div class="splCont">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would set them all to something on being loaded.

```
$('.splLink').load(function() {
    $(this).val("Show");
})
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/BrNQL/1/)

Integrated into your existing initialisation:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".splLink").click(function() {
        $(this).next().slideToggle("fast");
        $(this).val($(this).val() == 'Show' ? 'Hide' : 'Show'); 
        return false; 
    }).val("Show");
});
```

Comment: @HashemQolami Maybe. But he may want to chain the jQuery off the `.click()` that he already has. That's what I did in the JSFIDDLE.

Comment: @SergeyL. I hadn't checked the fiddle. Wasn't in context.

Comment: @Sergey L. Thanks. 
This exactly that I wanted to do.

Answer (score 1):

In HTML, the way to set the value of a button is to use the `value` attribute. If you don't want to use that, you could set the default value programmatically with the jQuery `val()` method:

```
$('input.splLink').val('My Value');
```